# Make system sounds louder than device

Tags: windows-7, audio

I want to make the Windows 7 system sound louder than the device audio in windows 7. The scenario is that I have music playing from pandora.com but I want to be able to hear the new email notification louder than the music.

In volume mixer I can set the system sound volume lower than the device but not louder (If I exceed the horizontal line from the device it raises the headphones volume). Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You need to lower the volume of what you want quiter not make one item louder.

Comment: @50-3 Thanks for the suggestion but when I reduce the volume it drags the system sound down with it. Basically I can't exceed the limit set by the device volume slider.

Comment: @50-3 Sorry I misunderstood what you were saying and I feel a bit stupid that I didn't figure that out myself :) Thanks Psycogeek for clarifying that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You need to lower an applications volume rather then raise another*

If you raise the volume of an application it will raise all others with it relatively, but if you select individual application you can lower them independently.

Open the Speaker Icon in the notifications tray (yellow) and select the Mixer.

[image]

Raise the level of the Speakers and the system sounds (green), then lower all the other applications (red) that would be to loud.

---

As an alternative , or to increase a system sound on a more permanent basis
[image]

Load the Wave sound found in the windows media folder into an audio editor, and increase the total digital range, then save it.